# Dynamic route code does nothing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

This is my twiddle to be more clear :

https://ember-twiddle.com/1454b9f4a64c197879d13f756401e561?openFiles=router.js%2C

I am trying to make a dynamic route. When I click a picture it should go to its detail page with different URL and different content. Like, when I click on the first pic it should go to localhost:4200/pic/1 or localhost:4200/1.

I'm trying to do the URL dynamic but I can't so far, when I click a picture it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Also, at the beginning I created routes and templates for every picture but with bigger data it won't be possible. How am I gonna handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by:

- Not using Ember-data....I'm not sure how to make that work in Ember Twiddle. I just used a plain array of objects.
- I passed in the model to the route in the `link-to`

Here is what the template looked like with the `pic` model passed to the route in the `link-to`:

```
{{outlet}}

{{#each model as |pic|}}
  <div>{{#link-to "pic" pic}}
     <img src={{pic.image}} width="300">
  {{/link-to}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

See my working twiddle here: https://ember-twiddle.com/4b2b6467199622ae740259622c76ba9b

Answer (score 1):

While using {{link-to}} helper for dynamic routes you must include the dynamic attributes also.

```
{{#each model as |pic|}}
  <div>{{#link-to 'pic' pic}}<img src={{pic.image}} width="300">{{/link-to}}</div>
{{/each}}{{outlet}}
```

Here the pic model is passed to the link-to helper.

But this wont work if you are directly accessing the page for a specific pic.

Also rename your models/images.js to pics.js. You must also remove the id attribute from pics model as Ember.js do not allow to set id manually.

Answer (score 1):

You are need to pass the parameter with `link-to` like

```
{{#link-to 'pic' pics}}
```

because you are accessing the id in the pic route from `params.id` but not send any parameter.

[twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3338739a9698342531113300b7cbd9a9)